# How to get the value of an input on enter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my first question on this site. I did tried the addtodo(todo) code it worked so i wanted make it work when i type and press enter.
i also tried some more stuff it doesnot work. i didnot get any error messages not in chrome nor in vscode. i am a beginner so my code might be messy. how much more details do you need. i am going to write a story if you dont submit (i am not kidding)

```js
const dateElement = document.querySelector('.date');
const input = document.querySelector('#text-bar')
const list = document.querySelector('.input')
//date stuff

const options = {
  weekday: "long",
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric"
};
const today = new Date();

dateElement.innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

function toodoo(todo) {
  const item =
    ` 
   <li><i class="far fa-circle" id="circle"></i></li> 
<li>${todo}</li>
<li>  <button class="edit">edit</button></li>
<li> <button class="remove">remove</button></li>
    `;
  const position = "beforeend";
  list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, item);


}



document.addEventListener("enter", function(event) {
  if (event.keycode == 13) {
    const todo = input.Value;
    if (todo) {
      toodoo(todo);
    };

  }
});
```

```css
* {
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px;
}

.middle-space {
  height: 70vh;
  border: 2px solid rgba(126, 125, 125, 0.671);
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

#text-bar {
  width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 3vh;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  background-image: url('download (1).jpeg');
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 8vh;
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid rgba(126, 125, 125, 0.671);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: white;
}

#button {
  color: greenyellow;
  font-size: 25px;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  .middle-space {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #text-bar {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  h1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/*remove edit*/

.input li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.input {
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#circle {
  background-color: white;
  color: greenyellow;
}

ul {
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
}

.edit {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.remove {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}

.middle-space ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <h1 class="date">h</h1>
  <div class="middle-space">
    <div class="input">
      <ul>
        <!--    <li><i class="far fa-circle" id="circle"></i></li> 
    <li>drinkcoffee</li>
     <li>  <button class="edit">edit</button></li>
     <li> <button class="remove">remove</button></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="text-bar" placeholder="write stuff or something magic will happen"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" id="button"></i></button>
  </div>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no event called "enter'. You should try 'keydown', instead. Also, your example is too long. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `input` variable decloration inside of enter-event. When DOM has been loaded script get the value of input which is empty. And nothing is happened with it. When you press Enter empty value get passed into todo variable

Comment: You do know that the `enter` event is not a thing, right?

Comment: You right) I just copied your code without even check events only replaced variables) Still the idea is in empty input value not an event

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you are looking for is similar to that of a `<form>` element in combination with the `submit` event.

The `enter` event does not exist, `keydown` and `keyup` do and your implementation looks like it derived from it. But scratch that.

Down here I've added a `<form>` element that wraps your `<input>` element. I've also added a `<button type="submit">` element to submit your form with a button.

Listen to the `submit` event on the form. The first thing you should do in the event handler (and this is important) is to cancel the default event with the `event.preventDefault()` method. This enables you to add your own behavior to a form submission.

```js
const dateElement = document.querySelector('.date');
const input = document.querySelector('#text-bar');
const list = document.querySelector('.input');

// Select the form element.
const form = document.querySelector('#todo-form');

// Date stuff.
const options = {
  weekday: "long",
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric"
};
const today = new Date();

dateElement.innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

function toodoo(todo) {
  const item = `
    <li>
      <i class="far fa-circle" id="circle"></i>
    </li> 
    <li>${todo}</li>
    <li>  
      <button class="edit">edit</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="remove">remove</button>
    </li>
  `;
  const position = "beforeend";
  list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, item);
}

// Listen for submit event on form. This is trigger by clicking a 
// submit button or pressing the enter key.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop form from actually submitting.
  const todo = input.value; // Mind the lowercase V.
  if (todo) {
    toodoo(todo);
  };
});
```

```css
* {
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px;
}

.middle-space {
  height: 70vh;
  border: 2px solid rgba(126, 125, 125, 0.671);
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

#text-bar {
  width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 3vh;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  background-image: url('download (1).jpeg');
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 8vh;
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid rgba(126, 125, 125, 0.671);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: white;
}

#button {
  color: greenyellow;
  font-size: 25px;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  .middle-space {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #text-bar {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  h1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/*remove edit*/

.input li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.input {
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#circle {
  background-color: white;
  color: greenyellow;
}

ul {
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
}

.edit {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.remove {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}

.middle-space ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <h1 class="date">h</h1>
  <div class="middle-space">
    <div class="input">
      <ul>
        <!--    <li><i class="far fa-circle" id="circle"></i></li> 
    <li>drinkcoffee</li>
     <li>  <button class="edit">edit</button></li>
     <li> <button class="remove">remove</button></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form id="todo-form">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="text" id="text-bar" placeholder="write stuff or something magic will happen"> 
      <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle" id="button"></i></button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```